# dayjs with i18next set locale not working

Tags: react-native, expo, i18next, dayjs

I use dayjs, and I want to change the locale with the current languages of i18next.language

but its not working, I get only the english format.

```
...
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
dayjs.locale(i18n.language);
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should also import the [required locale](https://day.js.org/docs/en/i18n/changing-locale#docsNav). It won't work unless:

```
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
import('dayjs/locale/en') // path must match with `i18n.language`

const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
dayjs.locale(i18n.language);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [i18next.resolvedLanguage](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#resolvedlanguage)

Something like this:

```
...
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
dayjs.locale(i18n.resolvedLanguage);
...
```

btw: it might be you're accessing i18n too early, alternatively try to check the [ready flag](https://react.i18next.com/latest/usetranslation-hook#not-using-suspense):

```
...
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
const { t, i18n, ready } = useTranslation();
if (!ready) return 'loading translations...'
dayjs.locale(i18n.resolvedLanguage);
...
```

or alternatively subscribe to the [language changed event](https://www.i18next.com/overview/api#onlanguagechanged) (somewhere where you init i18next):

```
...
i18next.on('languageChanged', function(lng) {
  import(`dayjs/locale/${lng}`).then(() => { // make sure you load the appropriate dayjs translations...
    dayjs.locale(lng);
  });
})
...
```

Comment: not working, get every time the english format

Comment: What is the output of i18n.resolvedLanguage?

Comment: de is the output

Comment: if de is the output, it means the i18next side is ok...

Comment: did you require the appropriate dayjs translations? https://day.js.org/docs/en/i18n/changing-locale => require('dayjs/locale/de')

Comment: no else I have to require 50 languages..

Comment: without that it will not work ‍♂️

Comment: Is there other libary where I can set a locale without require hundred languages ?

Comment: Maybe luxon? https://dev.to/adrai/how-to-properly-internationalize-a-react-application-using-i18next-3hdb#formatting

Comment: but then I get this error if I use it from dev.to https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/tr0phv/why_i_get_this_error_message_typeerror_undefined/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71665124/i18next-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-i18next-default-services-format/71665382#71665382

Comment: I'm wondering if you don't face this: "Changing the global locale doesn't affect existing instances." at https://day.js.org/docs/en/i18n/changing-locale

Answer (score 0):

import it from 'dayjs/locale/it' like so

```js
import dayjs from 'dayjs';
```

And use it like so

```js
dayjs.locale({...it});
```